# using existing ios framework for unity. how to find replacement of viewController

Tags: ios, swift, unity-game-engine

i am writing ios plugins for existing ios framework.

in framework, there is already a method like:

```
public func present(from parentController: UIViewController, key: String, completionHandler handler: @escaping (Bool, String) -> Void) {
}
```

i understand a bit how to communicate with unity <-> swift framework.
but i am facing a challenge like,

i have a basic UI, canvas and buttons. i want that when user tap on button, it should call above framework method.
i know how to call a unity method when button tap.

**But how can i call above method from unity, with button tap, as unity is not aware of UIViewController.**

*please note: ios side is a framework, not an app, so framework is not aware of any UIKit stuffs.*

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem you are having is that you are trying to code 1:1 Swift operations in Unity when you might want to think about encapsulation.

It might be easier to have a single proxy/middleman component in your Swift code that performs operations on behalf of your Unity code.  In this way much of the complexity and iOS-specific aspects are hidden (encapsulated) away from your Unity code.  After all, all your Unity code might be concerned about is that a *certain window be shown*, it does **not** care *how* it is done.

So you might expose a very simple contract to Unity like (pseudo code):

```
ShowWindow (string name, callback allDone);
```

...then in your Unity code:

```
PluginManager pluginManager; // a set of predefined [DllImport]s

void OnZapRobotClicked()
{
   pluginManager.ShowWindow ("ZapRobot", () => { Debug.Log("Done"); } );
}
```

When `ShowWindow` is called in your Swift code, you use the appropriate  Swift APIs to display the appropriate view with the appropriate controller.  How that is done exactly is no different to showing windows in Swift at the best of times.

Now instead of having to code up a zillion `[DllImport]`s Unity-side  just to show a single window, you simply have **one method per feature** that you want to expose, **ShowWindow** being the very first.    You might have other methods like **SendMessage**, **LoadSettings**, **SaveSettings**, **DisablePlugin**.

Depending on how you are designing your plugin system, you might want to consider making this main proxy plugin the router that directs commands from your C# code to the appropriate plugin Swift-side.